# simple_form collection labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I want to use labels for collection items (for example, their translations).

```
= simple_form_for(@client) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
    .form-inputs
      = f.input :name, label: t('client.name')
      = f.input :level, collection: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        label_method: ????
        label: t('client.level')
    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, value: t('client.submit')
```

I am trying to figure out, what to use for `label_method` above.
I would like to have label_method to map to translations as in `map {|s| t("client.#{s}")}`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you don't already have a label method, you can pass a lambda to get the result you want

```
label_method: ->(obj){ t("client.#{obj}") }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It's worth pointing out what I missed at first:  change to double quotation marks (`"`) around the string so it will do the `#{obj}` substitution.

Comment: I needed to [add a HTML tag before each collection element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758782/how-do-you-add-a-tag-before-each-radio-button-in-simple-form) and this solution has been really helpful to me as well.