# How do you add a tag before each radio button in Simple Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

Simple necessity, but clearly no easy way to do it with Simple Form.

I need to put a `span` before each radio `input` in a Rails form that uses Simple form. I've successfully added a `span` to a *text* input as stated in [this guidelines](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form), but I cannot make out how to do the same thing with radio buttons (as well as check boxes).

I don't want to use jQuery, which I am currently using as a workaround.

---

### UPDATE 1

As @TarynEast asked in a comment, I tried creating an initializer with the following code I've been able to prepend a `span` tag to a string `input`.

#### Initializer

```
# config/initializers/simple_form__spanner
class SpannerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options)
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)

    spanner_input = "<span></span>"
    spanner_input << @builder.text_field(attribute_name,merged_input_options)
    return spanner_input.html_safe
  end
end
```

#### View

```
# the view code
<%= ff.input :xxx, label: 'XXX', as: :spanner %>
```

#### HTML Output

```
# the output in view
<div class="form-group spanner optional xxx">
  <div class="control-label-wrap">
    <label class="control-label spanner optional" for="xxx_1">XXX</label>
  </div>
  <span></span> 
  <input class="form-control spanner optional" type="text" value="some value" name="xxx[1]" id="xxx_1">
</div>
```

Now I'd love to be able to do the same with radio buttons and checkboxes. The output should be something like:

```
<label><span></span><input ... ></label>
<label><span></span><input ... ></label>
<label><span></span><input ... ></label>
```

---

### UPDATE 2

### (almost a solution)

I have something that can somehow do what I want, i.e. having a `span` per input in a collection of radio buttons or checkboxes. It outputs the span after the `input` tag, but before the text so it kinda works.

The solution doens't make use of any initializer, it's just a *lambda* that runs for every object in the collection.

#### Assuming you have an array which called `choices`:

```
choices = [ 
  { label: "Foo", value: "foo" },
  { label: "Bar", value: "bar" }
]
```

#### View

```
# the view code
<%= ff.input :xxx, 
      collection: choices, 
      label_method: -> (choice){ "<span></span>#{ choice[:label] }".html_safe } %>
```

#### Output

```
<label><input ... ><span></span> Foo </label>
<label><input ... ><span></span> Bar </label>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the text one? and what you tried for the radio button (even if it didn't work)?

Comment: I added the attempt with the string input. I added also what can be a solution. It's doesn't exactly do what I wanted but it's very close and can work for me.